# Javascript hide the scroll after clicking and reach the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using this in my website:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/scrolltop.htm

and it works great for me. But the only thing that I face is that when I click on the picture, it's opacity become 0 but there is still a link in the same place of the picture. I want to hide the link as well!
I have tried display none for the css in the js file but reached nothing!

Comment: What picture are you talking about? The ones I tried all seemed to work out

Comment: The arrow once u scroll down 100px, and then if u click it, scroll page up, if u go down to the bottom the image is visibly hidden but still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(top < 50){
        $('.handle').fadeOut(100);
    } else{
        $('.handle').fadeIn(100);
    }

});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/EJjvt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:1}, this.setting.fadeduration[0])//find
this.$control.stop().fadeIn(this.setting.fadeduration[0])//replace
```

find and replace the lines above, and also look for other animate({opacity}) functions and use them using common sense :)
when its opacity:0 use fadeOut

**Other wise leave everything as it is**

and use this

```
function mychecker(){
   if(!$('#topcontrol').is(':visible')){
       $(this).hide();
   }
   setTimeout(function (){mychecker();},100);
}
```

the above will check every so often if the thing is visible or not and then hide the contents properly :)

Comment: I have tried it and the link become successfully hidden but the picture didn't appear neither before nor after clicking on it.
Can I use fadeOut and fadeIn with opacity?

Comment: you do not need to use opacity at all, coz fade out takes care of that, but you have about 4 lines you need change. also unless fadeduration is 0 [zero] then it should work fine :)